# Overwrite S3 files using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a use-case where after performing a join between two datasets, I need to write each row to a separate file (updating existing file) on S3. Does Spark support this?

If not, can we use S3 client explicitly to write each entry to a new file in S3? Are there any side-effects that I should be aware of?

Comment: "write each row to a separate file"..  This is not a valid use case for s3. S3 is usually a very bad storage for tons of small files.  So unless you have just a handful of records, I advise against using S3 like that.  (Using DataFrameWriter to a database would be better IMO)

Answer (score 0):

it's not about Spark.. S3 doesn't support update, you should store the whole block at once.

in theory you  could use [multipart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html) (MPU)  to join multiple s3 object parts, however MPU is intended to support upload bigger than 5GB and minimal part size is 5MB

Each job can create new S3 object ( [example](https://hortonworks.github.io/hdp-aws/s3-spark/index.html))

Comment: I apologise if it was not clear in the question but by update, what I meant was overwriting the S3 file by changing the content. Will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, tons of small files in S3 are usually a bad practice.  That said, if you only have a limited amount of records to write, there are different options.

Here are some examples:

- use the DataFrameWriter, overwrite mode and partitionBy by a unique
  column
- use df.rdd.mapPartitions and write each records to S3
  manually using hadoop S3FileSystem.

Good luck.